# Sharepoint 2013 ,Forced due to logging gap, cached Error when trying to open page on other language

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

i have a page it was working on english version and arabic also, last week we got some problem in the server so we restore it to 1 week before and the english page works fine but when try to open arabic version i got this error

```
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 12/07/2019 09:39:25.00, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.1406009
```

Category : Database , EventID: ahjqp.

```
[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose]GetUriScheme[/ar/Pages/Home.aspx]
```

Category : General, EventID: g3ql.

i read some answers but i don't know if it's the same problem

Comment: Using VM snapshots/online backups are unsupported with SharePoint farms. You need to provide a verbose log file, though. `Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx`.

Comment: Your posted log messages are no indication for an error. They get logged all around also in health farms. You should dig a little more deeper in your ULS-Logs and provide those here.